# How to display crosshair selected value on x-axis and selected date on y-axis on Highcharts / Highstock?

Tags: javascript, plugins, charts, highcharts

I am working on this project which includes displaying historical data on an interactive chart. I came to the conclusion that Highcharts / Highstock is the best alternative as it provides the most options of customization. What I am trying to achieve is to display the selected value and its according date on the x-axis and y-axis respectively once I hover over a point, and this for every point I hover on. I want the chart to have a similar layout to the Yahoo chart:

[image: Yahoo chart displaying crosshair with value and date on the axes]

As you can see from the chart above, no matter on what point I hover on, the crosshair will move accordingly and will show the date of the selected point on the x-axis and the price on the y-axis, in which if I move to the left the date label moves to the left as well and the same goes to the price label on the y-axis which moves up and down according to the chart trend showing the "*Close*" of the current stock. I have been researching on how to achieve this looking through the documentation and digging my way through the forum and I have not found any solution. I came as close as to this fiddle I found:

- http://jsfiddle.net/r7fdh/

This fiddle, however, uses `event.PageY` and `event.PageX` instead of the default crosshair that comes with the library. Apart from that, it shows the entire range of prices e.g. I only have 6 data points and if I hover over the points the crosshair shows much more than that, basically the entire y-axis. If I get out of the chart range it will still show data (negative numbers) which cannot be the correct.

I know this is possible as I have found a chart which was produced with highcharts / highstock by looking at the source code and it does the same as the Yahoo chart with a slight difference in design. This is the chart:

[image: Chart displaying crosshair labels with according value, volume and date on the x-axis and y-axis accordingly]

The black horizontal line (black rectangle y-axis [127.62]) from the chart above was created with a plugin:

- http://jsfiddle.net/RolandBanguiran/nf7ne/

Are there any options to produce crosshair labels as in the chart above? Any documentation? Perhaps plugins? I am open to any suggestions and thank all you guys in advance for any help you can provide. King regards!!

Comment: Could you point me which values are incorrect in that scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/nf7ne/51/ ? Because mentioned crosshairs seems to working properly.

Comment: Hi @SebastianBochan if you look at this fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/r7fdh/) you can see that if you hover beneath the x-axis, values appear negative which do not fit with the chart criteria and the crosshairs separate from each other. Hypothetically, the values are correct on the view of the pointer's position and coordinates but is not really what I am looking for. What I would like to achieve is a similar principle but with the default crosshair showing the value in a label only for the data points. Go to yahoo.finance and hover over the interactive charts you will notice a difference.

Comment: You can add a condition which check if mouse is "out of plotarea". Example: http://jsfiddle.net/r7fdh/63/

Comment: Thanks @SebastianBochan this is getting really close. Can this be done with the default crosshair that comes with the library? So instead of `event.PageY` and `event.PageX` something under the chart options like perhaps `tooltip.crosshair` and then the code to show the price on the y-axis equivalent to the crosshairs y-coordinates? Thanks for bearing with me. Best regards!!

Comment: One more thing that might help. Take a look at this [link](http://www.investing.com/equities/apple-computer-inc) it contains the chart from my question which also used highstock. If you click on candlestick, that is precisely what I am looking for (those crosshairs) and I tried looking at the source code but somehow the way the chart is build is very complex. The site uses an external javascript for the "custom" charts and I tried to read my way through but could not find anything. I know the answer is there somewhere but sadly sometimes my javascript knowledge does not reach to such levels.

Comment: Here is the external javascript [file](http://glocdn.investing.com/js/jscharts-8.2.min.js)